# My boxes gets lost behind the images [HTML]

Tags: html

Firstly i would like to say hello, this is my first question ever and it's been bugging me for awhile. I'm a newbie at html coding and i'd like to keep learning, it's interesting. Anyways to the question.

When i try to move a textbox over an image it gets lost behind the image like this:

```
<div style="background-color:#x;width:500px;height:300px;">&nbsp;</div>
 <p><img alt="" src="x" style="width:800px;height:401px;margin-top:-400px;margin-left:"/></p>
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: well, i was trying to learn layout coding, but i'm really really a newbie so yeah.

Comment: Where is the "textbox" in this?

Comment: oh pardon me i should name it box instead

Comment: What would you like to happen? For the text box to be in front of the image?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps, but try using the z-index property
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is better to read the whole HTML tutorial on w3schools. http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

If you want an image at the background of an text, set the image as a background!